# Tomcat 7 + JSF 1.2 convertNumber error

Tags: jsf, tomcat, tomcat7

I work with tomcat 6 and everything works ok, but I need to change to tomcat 7 and where I use convertNumber I receive the error:

> /pages/pvt/ipd/cliente/consultar.xhtml @37,105 value="#{clientePocketController.cliente.codcliente}": **Can't set property 'codcliente' on class** 'br.com.mili.entities.geral.cliente.Cliente' to value '1.793'.

```
<h:inputText id="txtCodCliente" value="#{clientePocketController.cliente.codcliente}" 
     converterMessage="Permitido apenas números.">
 <f:convertNumber integerOnly="true" minIntegerDigits="0"  pattern="######" locale="pt_BR"/>
 <f:validateLength maximum="6" />
```

My property codcliente is Integer, Tomcat 7 is withi el-api-2.2.0.jar and el-impl-2.2.jar.
Id be happy for any help.

Comment: Does not seem to be caused by the Tomcat version, but the code you deploy seems to be different `Can't set property 'codcliente' on class 'br.com.mili.entities.geral.cliente.Cliente` - that's one of your classes.

Comment: Thanks Johannes for reply, but if I remove the tag f:convertNumber, it works...

Comment: I made a mistake. I changed the tomcat's lib el-api.jar, but I shouldn't... Thank you, solved.